# How to plot two different data sets of same column using echarts4r?

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have sample data for two datasets:

```
one <- data.frame(
  Timestamp = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2023-07-01"), by = "days", length.out = 5),
  `Heat Capacity` = c(10, 15, 8, 12, 20)
)


two <- data.frame(
  Timestamp = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2023-07-01"), by = "days", length.out = 3),
  `Heat Capacity` = c(8, 12, 6)
)
```

Without combining the two dataframes, can a line chart be formed using `echarts4r`?

I have done it using `ggplot`:

```
one_graph <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = one, aes(x = one[[1]], y = one[[2]])) +
  geom_line(data = two, aes(x = two[[1]], y = two[[2]]))
```

Can the same be achieved using `echarts4r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible:

```
library(echarts4r)

one |> e_charts(Timestamp) |> 
    e_line(serie = Heat.Capacity) |> 
    e_data(data = two) |> 
    e_line(serie = Heat.Capacity)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to plot data with lot of rows and I have doubt that which would be faster ggplot2 or echarts4r for plotting . When I use ggplot2 inside a shiny App it gives me a slight delay

Comment: You should ask a separate question for this.

Comment: (I guess you should accept this answer since it seems to do exactly what you asked for)